# Run application automatically when system back from hibernate

Tags: java, windows, javafx, inno-setup

I want to start my application automatically for all users, whenever system starts from shutdown or hibernate (I don't want user manually click on my exe icon to run application). For example, if same system is used by two users, it should work for both users.

I've tried following, but it is not working for all users, neither for start from hibernate:

1. I had added my exec shortcut in shell:startup
2. I m also using batch file code like this  REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run /v JApp /t REG_SZ /d  /h "%~MoodOMeter.exe"
   now a problem which i  m getting is that it only works for current user i.e if it registers on startup folder on userid 1 then it will not run for userid 2 and the last thing that not working is that if system start  from hibernate then it will not run automatically  can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: @MartinPrikryl There's no real obligation to accept answers, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers) for example. This also has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  I can accept the answer only if it helps me and other but some answer are not very clear so i have not accepted as answer if it help me then only i accept answer

Comment: @MartinPrikryl because of that hasn't helped me actually I found my problem itself

Comment: @MartinPrikryl  thanks next time I will keep in mind and what about this current one can you help or you keep on giving negative

Comment: Your solution 2. is correct in general, though your description is rather vague. Show us what does your registry key look like. + Hibernate part is a completely separate question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It not about Java hibernate it about window hibernate would you help . My app not run when system start from hibernate

Comment: I understand what "hibernate" you mean. But running application on Windows start and running application on resuming from hibernate are two separate question. + Are you really sure you need to re-run the application after resuming? It should be already running by that time (as it was already run when the machine was started).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes, I want to re run application I know it's running on background . Reason for rerun application is because my app never popup when system resume from hibernate

Comment: What does it mean *"never popup"*?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl when system start myexec app automatically start i.e my exec window visible to user I want my exec window visible to user when my system resume (hibernate)

Comment: OK, but if you re-run it on resume, it will run twice (while one instance may be invisible), wasting system resources. Consider making your application detect the resuming and popup on it own.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i had written  a code when system start my exec run take feedback of user per day and application get close suppose user does not shutdown his system (i.e click on hibernate ) then my application never run again that why i want to re run my application when system back from hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Task Scheduler to trigger an action on resuming system](https://superuser.com/q/276054/213663).

But Task Scheduler has its limitation (in context of your question).

You can setup the task in two modes:

- For specific account with *"Run whether user is logged on or not"* option. For that you need to know a password of some local account. And the task will run with privileges of that account, so not with privileges of the logged on account. That would be problem, if you need to write files or registry in user profile. Not to mention that there can be multiple logged on users at the same time (the task would be run for one of them only).
- With *"Run when user is logged on"* option, you won't need the password and the task is run with correct privileges, but only for the account that created the task. So if you create the task in installer, it would be executed only for the account that run the installer. To solve this, you can make the application itself create the task, when it's executed (and the task does not exists yet).

If the above limitation is ok, then it's a solution.

---

Other way is to keep your application running in the background and monitor the system to trigger your desired action on resuming.